# Deleting Columns Between Two Bounds in Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I will be generating large matrices based on a script, and these matrices are m x n matrices can get quite big sometimes. I was wondering if it was possible at all to specify two bounds, b1 and b2, and delete all columns outside of those two bounds.

So say I had

```
 0.1  0.2  0.3   0.24  0.11  0.09  0.12  0.2
 0.7  0.3  0.03  0.43  0.15  0.19  0.99  0.04
 0.9  0.2  0.32  0.14  0.15  0.01  0.91  0.12
```

And I wanted to keep everything between the 3rd and 5th column, I would need

```
  0.3   0.24  0.11
  0.03  0.43  0.15
  0.32  0.14  0.15
```

Comment: Usw the colon operator to index the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the colon (`:`) operator is for (See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)).  You can select a range of indices along a particular dimension, by specifying the bounds on each side of the colon.  In your case, if you want the columns between `b1` and `b2`, you would do

```
subMat = mat(:, b1:b2);
```

If you don't specify any bounds, then it will select everything along that dimension.  So intuitively, this will select all rows, and all columns between `b1` and `b2`